# Showing data from two different wordpress blogs on the same external page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display information from two different wordpress blogs on an external page on the same server. Everything seems to work just fine - information from the first blog is requested first and displayed properly.

However, when the first loop (info from the first blog) starts, it doesn't seem to end and affects the second loop. Thus the second request for information from the second blog (the last post on the blog) returns information from the first blog.

Is there a way to actually use the `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` multiple times by using different paths the the wp-blog-header.php on the same page?

This is the source that I have so far:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../path1/wp-blog-header.php');
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=4');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
echo '<li><a href="';
the_permalink();
echo '" title="';
the_title();
echo '" target="_blank">';
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
echo '</a></li>';
endforeach;
?>
[...]
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../path2/wp-blog-header.php');
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=1');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
echo '<h2>';
the_title();
echo '</h2><p>';
the_excerpt();
echo '</p>';
endforeach;
?>
```

If I disable the first loop, the second loop works fine and gets info from the second blog. If the first loop is enabled, the second loop displays information from the first blog.

I don't seem to find any information on this issue.
I am novice in PHP.

Thanks for any help!

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

to use a header multiple times you should use

```
require_once('./wp-blog-header.php')
```

**Edited**
 I have edited ur code with `each_connect` ,by this the first loop's post data will not be displayed in the next loop.

```
<?php
$posts = new WP_query(); 
// Find connected pages (for all posts)
p2p_type( 'posts' )->each_connected( $wp_query );
?

<?php
require_once('../path1/wp-blog-header.php');
$posts->query('numberposts=4'); 
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
foreach ( $post->connected as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
echo '<li><a href="';
the_permalink();
echo '" title="';
the_title();
echo '" target="_blank">';
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
echo '</a></li>';
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata(); // set $post back to original post
endwhile; 
?>
[...]
<?php
require_once('../path2/wp-blog-header.php');
$posts->query('numberposts=1'); 
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
foreach ( $post->connected as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
echo '<li><a href="';
the_permalink();
echo '" title="';
the_title();
echo '" target="_blank">';
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
echo '</a></li>';
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata(); // set $post back to original post
endwhile; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Amirtha!

Please, see the updated question. I've added the code I have got so far. I tried with require and require_once, but it's still not working.

Comment: Try using `wp_reset_postdata();`  after the end of first loop or  before the `require_once()` method which at the beginning of the next loop

Comment: Tried, doesn't work either. Tried the `wp_reset_query();` too--nope :(

Answer (score 0):

They must be in different directories so if you will eb providing path of different directories it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question with the code I've got so far. The two blogs are in two different directories.